# How can i get my program to reject letter inputs, and only accept number inputs?

Tags: python

Thank you guys for helping me :)
I'm new to Python and really appreciate the helpful responses you guys give

edit - i have solved my problem

here is what i did to solve it

```
i = False
while i == False:
    Type = input("Please enter a number from 1-6")
    if Type.isdigit():
        i = True
    else:
        i = False
```

Comment: Your mistake is that whenever you redefine `Type`, `checknum` will not be updated unless you redefine it too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
Type = input("Please enter your choice of slab -->")

checknum = Type.isdigit()

while not checknum:
    Type = int(input("Please enter a value from 1-6"))
    checknum=Type.isdigit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how:

```
Type = input("Please enter your choice of slab -->")

while True:
    if Type.isdigit():
        break
    Type = input("Please enter a value from 1-6")
```